# Duplicate query conditions: __raw__

Tags: mongoengine

I made custom QuerySet:

> ```
> class CustomQuerySet(QuerySet):
>     def get_campaign(self, name=None):
>         query = {'campaigns': {
>                 '$elemMatch': {
>                 '_syskey': name or 'default'}}}
>         return self.filter(__raw__=query)[0]
>
>
> class Client(Document):
>
>     ...
>
>     meta = { 
>         'collection': 'my_collection',
>         'allow_inheritance': False,
>         'indexes': ['client_id', ],
>         'queryset_class': CustomQuerySet
>       }
> ```

Run into console:

> ```
> client = Client.objects(client_id=2)
> client.get_campaign('default')
> client.get_campaign('default')
> # here exception is born 
> InvalidQueryError: Duplicate query conditions: __raw__
> ```

If I will repeat 1 and 2 command again the exception is not appear:

> ```
> client = Client.objects(client_id=2)
> client.get_campaign('default')
> ```

but after 3 line exception is repeated:

> ```
> client.get_campaign('default')
> ```

What is it? How decide it?